# How to solve error of missing destination file operand after '/sdcard/ngrok/ngrok ' in termux

Tags: cp, android

I am using termux in my android but I get the following error when I want to copy some data from `sdcard` to `$HOME` IN TERMUX the following
error shows up:
`missing destination file operand after '/sdcard/ngrok/ngrok'`
here are commands:

```
   $ cp /sdcard/ngrok/ngrok
   cp: missing destination file operand after '/sdcard/ngrok/ngrok'   
   try 'cp --help' for more information.
```

Answer (score 5):

You said that you want to copy file from `sdcard to $HOME`, but your `cp` command doesn't have destination. Format of copy command is `cp source destination`. So right command is

```
cp sdcard/ngrok/ngrok $HOME
```

Make sure that `sdcard/ngrok/ngrok` is a file. If it is a directory then use `-r` option i.e.

```
cp -r sdcard/ngrok/ngrok $HOME
```

Also try `cp --help` for more information about `cp` command.

Comment: Thanks but it's not working friend

Comment: @Ronny What is the error?

Comment: @Ronny may be it is not file, if it directory then use `-r` option. See update.